# 2FA through azure ad with [entity id and ACS]

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

We want to implement microsoft 2FA in our mvc application. our network team asked 2 things to share.

1-Entity ID

2- ACS URL

How can we implement entity ID and ACS URL in MVC application. Any help will be highly appreciated.

We have analyzed entity id is unique and ACS is our application url where we have deployed.

But we are unable to identify how entity id and ACS method look.

Comment: See following : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-active-directoryad-authentication-using-asp-net-core-6/?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0):

> we are unable to identify how entity id and ACS method look.

***1-Entity ID***

Entity ID can be found in the Registered Application in AAD.

The syntax of the EntityID will be like below.

```cs
https://**********/YourTenantID/
```

Navigate to the `AAD` => `App Registration` => `Your App` => `Endpoints`.

You can see the endpoint related to SAML at the bottom.

[image]

***2- ACS URL***

As per this [Doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/blog/azure-media-service-aad-auth-and-acs-deprecation/), ACS has been deprecated.

Instead use the authorization endpoint.

[image]

Refer this [Azure AD SAML](https://workos.com/docs/integrations/azure-ad-saml) for more details.

I found a package reference [`Sustainsys.Saml2.Mvc`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sustainsys.Saml2.Mvc/1.0.2).

> The package adds an MVC controller that handles the SAML SignIn and SignOut.

Also refer this [SOThead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004628/how-should-i-implement-samlp-2-0-in-an-asp-net-mvc-4-service-provider) which explains the similar kind of issue.

Comment: Can you please share the sample code for this we checked Sustainsys.Saml2.Mvc. web.config but it is not working. <sustainsys.saml2 entityId="https://login.microsoftonline.com/edf442f5-b994-4c86-a131-b42b03a16c95/saml2" returnUrl="https://localhost:44385/">
  <identityProviders>
   <add entityId="https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/Metadata" signOnUrl="https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" binding="HttpRedirect">
    <signingCertificate fileName="~/App_Start/UNO-InSights-cer.cer" />
   </add>
  </identityProviders>